# Bat file para rodar arquivo.r

Tags: r, batch

Gostaria de usar um arquivo .bat para rodar determinado arquivo.r diariamente com o taskmanager do windows, mas não estou conseguindo fazê-lo rodar.

Meus passos:
1) abrir notepad

2) digitar código, que atualmente é:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.0\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" --vanilla  "G:\Macroeconomia\Economistas\Coleta\Prohort\Prohort.R"
```

3) salvar o arquivo em formato .bat

4) dois cliques para rodá-lo

Entretanto o bat não roda inteiro, ele só carrega os pacotes do meu código e fecha.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "ele só carrega os pacotes do meu código e fecha"?

Comment: O início do meu código de R é uma função que carrega todos os pacotes necessários para rodar o código, então quando eu rodo o bat, dá pra ver "loading packages", aí então fecha

Comment: Se ele fecha, é por que terminou a execução. Coloque um `pause` na lina abaixo, da sua.

Comment: mas ele não está executando até o final, tanto que os arquivos que ele gera não estão sendo atualizados

Comment: Por padrão, o Windows fecha o terminal quando algum script termina de rodar. Eu recomendo entrar no terminal, navegar até onde o arquivo `Prohort.R` está (i.e., o diretório específico dentro do drive G:) e rodar `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.0\bin\i386\Rscript.exe" CMD BATCH Prohort.R`. Isto vai gerar um arquivo `Prohort.Rout` e dentro dele vai estar o log do R. Aí vai ser possível ver o que deu errado no teu script. Ou seja, descobrir porque ele está apenas carregando os pacotes, sem rodar mais nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como falado pelo colega Marcos Nunes: 
Por padrão, o Windows fecha o terminal quando algum script termina de rodar. Eu recomendo entrar no terminal, navegar até onde o arquivo `Prohort.R` está (i.e., o diretório específico dentro do drive G:) e rodar `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.0\bin\i386\R.exe" CMD BATCH Prohort.R`. Isto vai gerar um arquivo Prohort.Rout e dentro dele vai estar o log do R. Aí vai ser possível ver o que deu errado no teu script. Ou seja, descobrir porque ele está apenas carregando os pacotes, sem rodar mais nada.

Assim, abrindo o arquivo .Rout como bloco de notas consegui visualizar o crash!

Answer (score 1):

@Danilo Imbimbo, fiz um script no R, que carrega pacotes e executa algumas tarefas também. Respondendo sua pergunta, quando você executa seu *.bat ele abre o cmd e fecha e você não vê nada por que provavelmente você não coloca nenhuma função no script que salva algum arquivo ou imagem. Se você cria um script que só gera objetos dentro do ambiente R, mas não usa nenhuma função para exportar os resultados para fora do ambiente R, você não verá os resultados (acredito que você queria ver as saídas do R, em algum lugar). Então você precisa editar seu script e colocar algumas funções como "write.table()" para salvar alguns objetos e por aí vai. O que você fez seria como se você abrisse o R, rodasse a análise e fechasse o R sem salvar nada.